# When using CSS Scale in Firefox, element keeps original position

Tags: css, firefox, zooming, scale

When using scale in Firefox, the scaled element dóes get scaled properly. The problem is, that it's positioned as if it isn't scaled.

This works fine in Chrome, and probably also in IE, Safari and Opera. These browsers all support the CSS zoom property, where Firefox doesn't. For Firefox I'm using -moz-transform: scale(0.3);.

This is my CSS:

```
#overview .page-content {
    zoom: 0.3;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.3);
}
```

This is what it should look like (as in Chrome):

[image: zoom in chrome]

This is what it shouldn't look like (as in Firefox):
[image: scale in firefox]

Does anybody know how to fix this? Or maybe a workaround?

Comment: Adding `position: absolute` and `-moz-transform-origin: 0 0` might help.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As [thirtydot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405015/thirtydot) mentioned:

```
position: absolute;
-moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
```

This will do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for posting this - you don't want to see the math I was trying to do to reposition the elements after scaling!

Comment: If I need to scale the whole body then, what would be the solution?

Answer (score 7):

I added -transform-origin: 0 0; and it still did not work.

Somehow in Chrome it collapsed to -webkit-transform-origin: 0;

So I changed it to -transform-origin: top left; and it works fine now.

Full code:

```
-moz-transform: scale(50%);
-moz-transform-origin: top left;
-o-transform: scale(50%);
-o-transform-origin: top left;
-webkit-transform: scale(50%);
-webkit-transform-origin: top left;
```

Answer (score 1):

If absolute positioning is not an option - and aware of according browser support - `display: table-cell` with a `min-width` definition, should needs be, might do the trick as well.

E.g. this helped me to get a row with customer logos scaling well across different screen resolutions.