# CSS: Wrong position of "transform: scale();" container children

Tags: css, css-position, transform, scale

I have a container element with long content which is scaled:

```
.container {
  transform: scale(0.9);
}
```

inside this container I have a child `div` which is used to be a popup. It's positioned absolute with top `50%`

```
.popup {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
```

but unfortunately when container is scaled this `50%` is not working. I need to use `~240%` if it appears on the bottom of a page.

Do you now some specifics on applying positioning on children of scaled elements?

**DEMO:** http://labs.voronianski.com/test/scaled-positioning.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When using CSS Scale in Firefox, element keeps original position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980648/when-using-css-scale-in-firefox-element-keeps-original-position)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Add to `.wrap`:

```
.wrap {
  ...
  position: relative;
  /*some prefix*/-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

You'll need to reposition the `.popup` (now the reference frame is the `.wrap`, instead of the `html` element), but in Chrome the scale toggle works fine after this change.

See: [When using CSS Scale in Firefox, element keeps original position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980648/when-using-css-scale-in-firefox-element-keeps-original-position)