# Transform scale change position element after in hover

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transforms

I try using `transform:scale(1.2)` to obtain the effect of an appearing circle around the icon. `transform` I added to the `.icon-style:hover::after`.

**Now this code is commented, please uncomment this code to see what I want to get.**

For example I trying doing something like this: [click](https://tympanus.net/Development/IconHoverEffects/#set-1). But `scale` change position circle.

I read this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18943773/css-wrong-position-of-transform-scale-container-children), but I don't now how to use `transform-origin` in my CSS.

Demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fkhuce62/1/)

```css
*{
    background-color: black;
}
.pos-footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 30px;
}
.icon-social {
    display: flex;
}
.icon-social-pos {
    position: relative;
}
.icon-style {
    position: relative;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center; 
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: background-color .3s ease-in-out;
}
.icon-style:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
.icon-style::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.425);
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 7px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}
.icon-style:hover::after {
    opacity: 1;
    /* transform: scale(1.2); */
}
.icon-github {
    background-image: url("https://img.icons8.com/windows/30/000000/github.png");
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.icon-linkedin {
    background-image: url("https://img.icons8.com/ios-glyphs/22/000000/linkedin-2.png");
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pos-footer">
    <div class="icon-social">
        <a href="#">
            <div class="icon-social-pos">
                <div class="icon-style icon-github"></div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
            <div class="icon-social-pos">
                <div class="icon-style icon-linkedin"></div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: unlike the accepted answer, you can add the scale at the end to avoid changing the origin (like in the duplicate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the transform in your hover (`.icon-style:hover::after`) is overwriting your `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`. A way to fix it is to add the translate to the hover too:

```
.icon-style:hover::after {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.2) translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Then you have to define your `transform-origin` in `.icon-style` to `top left;`

```css
*{
    background-color: black;
}
.pos-footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 30px;
}
.icon-social {
    display: flex;
}
.icon-social-pos {
    position: relative;
}
.icon-style {
    position: relative;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center; 
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: background-color .3s ease-in-out;
}
.icon-style:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
.icon-style::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform-origin: top left;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.425);
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 7px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}
.icon-style:hover::after {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.2) translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.icon-github {
    background-image: url("https://img.icons8.com/windows/30/000000/github.png");
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.icon-linkedin {
    background-image: url("https://img.icons8.com/ios-glyphs/22/000000/linkedin-2.png");
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pos-footer">
    <div class="icon-social">
        <a href="#">
            <div class="icon-social-pos">
                <div class="icon-style icon-github"></div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
            <div class="icon-social-pos">
                <div class="icon-style icon-linkedin"></div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: move the scale after the translation to avoid changing the origin